# How to use Linq in Python.net

Tags: python, .net, extension-methods, ironpython, python.net

I've been using IronPython for a while now, but it seems it is not very compatible with some modules that use sockets. Therefore I am looking for an alternative such as Python.net. I got it all to work, except for Linq.

In IronPython I can simply do:

`clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)`

But this is not possible in Python.net. Is it possible to use Linq within Python.net and how do I load the Linq extension?

Thanks,
Arnold

Comment: there is open issue for this and some ideas how to implement it on top of DLR: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/55

Comment: In my point of view, this depending on whether Python.net supports extension methods or not.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was only using the FirstOrDefault Linq method in my code, so I decided to refactor all the occurrences to a Python implementation.